# CPU Usage on Asus 1015BX using VAAPI (Lubuntu 12.10)

Tags: multimedia

I installed and configured VAAPI support and mplayer-vaapi on my Asus 1015BX.
Now when watching 1080p HD movies the average CPU usage is around 25%.
Is it a correct usage?
Or it is still too much?

My Laptop:

Asus 1015BX
CPU: AMD C-60 Dual Core 1.00 GHz
GPU: Radeon 6290

Answer (score 0):

With a *1.0 GHz processor* that's a brilliant result I would say for a regular bitrate 1080p movie.

Keep in mind that only video decoding is offloaded. Other stuff like sound, demuxing the container (e.g. MKV), I/O operations, etc. are still CPU-bound.